# Change Django Rest Framework Paginated Output Format

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When serializing and paging using DRF the output of the API assumes the following format.

```
{
    "count": 4429,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/component_log/?limit=100&offset=100",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [{...},{...},{...}]

}
```

This includes the count, next, and previous fields as well as the results field.

Is there any way to serialize and paginate while **only** returning the results array?

eg

```
[{...},{...},{...}]
```

---

### My Serializer

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = '__all__'
```

### My ViewSet

```
class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,UpdateModelMixin):

    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter,)
```

---

Without paging you are able to achieve this with the following added to the REST_FRAMEWORK setting.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer'
    ),
}
```

but this does not carry over to paged requests.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't define or set any pagination classes in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a [Custom pagination class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles) for your view and override the `get_paginated_response` method, like this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: I literally just stumbled upon this in the docs. I dont know how i over looked it. I will mark this as accepted as soon as i can. PS is the response method you used the django.http.response or another?

Comment: it is the drf Response, `from rest_framework.response import Response`